# Discord bot displays hours as 00 in strftime statement

Tags: python, discord, strftime

I am creating a Discord bot. When you enter the command, it is supposed to give a timestamp of the current time. I did this with `strftime`. But whenever the command is entered, the hours keep coming up as 00. The minutes and seconds display properly, just the hours is always 00.

```
@bot.command()
async def start(ctx):
    if session.is_active:
        await ctx.send("Always look to the future!")
        return
    
    session.is_active = True
    session.start_time = ctx.message.created_at.timestamp()
    human_readable_time = ctx.message.created_at.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    positive_reminder.start()
    await ctx.send("Positive thoughts fuel a positive mind. Started at {}".format(human_readable_time))
```

The message should say exactly what is listed above: `Positive thoughts fuel a positive mind. Started at 07.08.32` (Time is a sample)

Output is: `Positive thoughts fuel a positive mind. Started at 00.08.32`

Comment: Is this a timezone issue? Are you always 7 hours behind?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm a little confused with your output and your code.  The code shows ```%H:%M:%S``` but your output is ```07.08.32```.   That code shouldn't produce that resulting format.

Comment: Actually, perhaps systems settings is the cause of the ```.``` instead of ```:```...

Comment: the '.' was a typo because i'm rushing myself lol. it reads with ':', as it should. it was a timezone thing, because i started this at 6pm my time, which makes it 00 in UTC. Smh, im new at this

Answer (score 0):

You need to add timezone info to the timestamp:

```py
import pytz

session.start_time = ctx.message.created_at.timestamp()
# Add timezone info to the timestamp
tz = pytz.timezone('UTC')
timestamp_with_tz = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(session.start_time).replace(tzinfo=tz)
human_readable_time = timestamp_with_tz.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Had to remove the utc from datetime.utcfromtimestamp, and replaced the ('UTC') with my timezone. Thanks so much! Hopefully I'll gain more practice and can help others in the future